# Sublevel set is an absorbing convex set

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

> Let $|| \cdot ||$ be a sublinear functional on a linear vector space $X$. Then the sublevel set $$K=\{ x \in K: ||x|| \leq 1\}$$ is an absorbing convex set and $0 \in K$.

What I've got so far:

It is easy to see that a set $K$ is convex since it contains balls $||x||\leq 1$ that are convex as well.

**Definition:** A subset $K$ of a linear vector space $X$ is called *absorbing* if $$X= \bigcup_{t\geq 0} tK$$ where $tK=\{tx:x\in K\}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $x\in X$, then either $\|x\|=0$ and $x\in K$ or $\|x\|>0$, whence $x/\|x\|\in K$.

Comment: @s.harp your explanation is for which part?

Comment: Thats the important step in seeing that $K$ is absorbing.

Comment: @s.harp I appreciate it but I need more explanation what all of what you wrote is :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ is absorbing if for every $x\in X$ you have a $t>0$ and an $a\in K$ with $t\cdot a= x$. So look at some $x\in X$ and try to find the relevant $t$ and $a$.

First take care of the case $\|x\|=0$. If this is the case then clearly $\|x\|≤1$ and then $x\in K$, so take $a= x$ and $t=1$.

Whats left is $\|x\|>0$, in this case note by sub-linearity that $\left\|\frac x{\|x\|}\right\|=1$ and hence $\frac{x}{\|x\|}\in K$, let this be your $"a"$, now choose $t=\|x\|$, then:
$$t\cdot a= \|x\|\cdot \frac{x}{\|x\|}=x$$
and the condition is verified also in the case that $\|x\|\neq 0$, hence $K$ is absorbing.